# Bi-annihilator of a subspace of the dual of an infinite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, duality

Let $V$ be an **infinite-dimensional** vector space and $V^*$ its dual.
For a linear subspace $W\subset V$ define $W^ \circ\subset V^*$ as the subspace of linear forms on $V$ vanishing on $W$.
Dually, for $\Gamma\subset V^*$ define $\Gamma^\diamond \subset V$ as the set of vectors $v\in V$ such that $\gamma(v)=0$ for all linear forms $\gamma\in \Gamma$.
It is slightly surprising but not too difficult to show that that we  have for all subspaces $W\subset V$ the equality $(W^\circ) ^\diamond=W$.
But is it true that for all $\Gamma\subset V^*$ we have $(\Gamma^\diamond)^\circ=\Gamma$ ?
And is there a reference (article, book, lecture notes,...) where this problem is mentioned?

Comment: A maybe-more accessible question that keeps it all on the dual side:  since $((\Gamma^\diamond)^\circ)^\diamond$ equals $\Gamma^\diamond$, we can ask:  if $\Gamma$ is contained in $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma^\diamond$ equals $\Lambda^\diamond$, then under what circumstances does $\Gamma$ equal $\Lambda$?

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case, you can’t get by without topology, in this case the weak topologies $\sigma(V,V^\ast)$ and $\sigma(V^\ast,V)$.  It is well known that the bipolars of subspaces of either of your spaces are precisely their closures for the corresponding topologies. So if they are not closed, then your claims will fail.

Comment: @user131781 Of course we can get by without topology: already two answers show this, just 17 minutes after the question was posted!

Comment: I think @user131781's [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369308/bi-annihilator-of-a-subspace-of-the-dual-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space#comment932332_369308) is less that the problem can't be stated, or even answered, without topology, and more that it is probably most useful to *think* of the problem in topological terms even if one is not *required* to do so (for example, this reveals 'heuristically' that the answer must be no, even if one is left to, as you and I did, construct a specific non-closed subspace).

Comment: For example, your surprising true fact is the statement that [all subspace are closed in the weak topology (with respect to the full algebraic dual)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak_topology_induced_by_the_algebraic_dual).

Comment: Dear LSpice, thank you for your  explanations. I know nothing about topological vector spaces but I appreciate your point that if I did I would have immediately realized that the question is quite easy, whereas in reality I spent much time coming up with a solution.

Comment: Maybe you can see Proposition 1.3.5 of the book "Hopf algebras" by David E. Radford

Answer (score 6):

No, $(\Gamma^\diamond)^\circ$ need not always equal $\Gamma$.  Let $\mathcal B$ be a basis for $V$, and let $\Gamma$ be the span of the 'dual' set $\{e_b \mathrel: b \in \mathcal B\}$, so $e_b(c)$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) $[b = c]$ for all $b, c \in \mathcal B$.  Then $\Gamma^\diamond$ is $0$, so $(\Gamma^\diamond)^\circ$ is all of $V^*$; but $\Gamma$ itself does not contain, for example, the element $\sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b$ of $V^*$.

Comment: Your symbol  $\sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b$ does not make sense because you cannot sum infinitely many non-zero vectors in a vector space.

Comment: Sure it [does](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369308/bi-annihilator-of-a-subspace-of-the-dual-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space/369312#comment932341_369312):  $\bigl(\sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b\bigr)(v) = \sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b(v)$ is a finitely supported sum for each $v \in V$.  I think that, as @user131781 [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369308#comment932332_369308), this is a convergent sum in a weak topology; but anyway it can be defined without direct reference to topology.

Comment: OK, I agree, what you write makes sense.  However I don't know about weak topology and I thank you  for your definition which doesn't make reference to topology.

Comment: The topology @user131781 [mentions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369308#comment932332_369308) is the [weak* topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak_and_weak*_topologies), weakest making all eval. fncls. continuous.  Since $\lim_{F \subseteq \mathcal B} \bigl(\sum_{b \in F} e_b\bigr)(v)$ equals $\bigl(\sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b\bigr)(v)$ for all $v \in V$, this topology must declare that $\lim_{F \subseteq \mathcal B} \sum_{b \in F} e_b$ equals $\sum_{b \in \mathcal B} e_b$ (the limit taken over the finite subsets $F$ of $\mathcal B$—the so called "unordered sum").

Comment: Thanks again for your clear explanations, LSpice. I have upvoted your answer and your comments.

Answer (score 3):

The equality is false in general.
Here is a counterexample: fix a basis $v_i, i\in I$ of $V$ and consider the set of coordinate linear forms $v^*_i, i\in I$.
These forms are linearly independant but **never form a basis** since $V$ is infinite-dimensional.
So complete these forms to a basis $(v^*_j), j\in J$ with $J\setminus I\neq\emptyset$.
Choose $l\in J\setminus I$ and put $J'=J\setminus \{l\}$
If you define $\Gamma \subset V^*$ as the vector space generated by the $v_j^*, j\in J'$, then $\Gamma^\diamond =0$ (since already the subspace of $V^*$ generated by the $v_i^*, i\in I$ kill all vectors in $V$) so that $\Gamma\subsetneq (\Gamma^\diamond)^\circ=\{0\}^\circ=V^*$ yielding the required counterexample.

Comment: This seems to be the same as [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/369312).

Comment: Yes, it is the same idea, but I posted my answer without seeing yours. The technical details are different and I find your formulation indeed simpler. Also I wrote a comment to your post which you should take into account.